# How to include a generic library when calling the headers

Tags: gcc, c, linux-headers

this code gives me error

```
#include <linux/mman.h>
```

no such file or diretory

while this works

```
#include </usr/include/linux/mman.h>
```

how do i change in order so i can use the first option?

Comment: Well, you could add `-I/usr/include` to your `gcc` command - however it shouldn't be necessary as `/usr/include` should be searched by default. Are you using a non-standard version of `gcc`?

Comment: @steeldriver thank you , yes i am using musl-gcc

Comment: Hmm... in that case, I suspect there are good reasons why it doesn't try to include your host system's header files

Answer (score 1):

You have to install the related development packages first by:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-libc-dev linux-headers-generic build-essential
```

Note: you can always find [related packages with header file on packages.ubuntu.com](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=focal&arch=amd64&mode=exactfilename&searchon=contents&keywords=linux%2Fmman.h).